# Error while loading an .arff file with scikit-learn

Tags: python, arff

I would like to use an Attribute-Relation File Format(.arff) with scikit-learn for a classification problem. The code runs fine on a Windows 10 machine, however when I try the same code on my other machine with Ubuntu(18.04.1) it throws a confusing error. Here is the code for loading the arff file:

```
import arff, numpy as np
dataset = arff.load(open('mydataset.arff'))
mydata = np.array(dataset['data'])
```

And the error I am getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/ml_classification.py", line 14, in <module>
    mydata = np.array(dataset['data'])
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

What could be the reason for this error and why does it only occur on one machine and not the other?

Comment: This has nothing to do with sklearn. `arff.load` returns a generator which you will first need to consume fully before converting to array. Which tutorial are you following? Why are you doing `dataset['data']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using an old or an unsupported library for ARFF. In order to find out details of the ARFF package you are using, try `pip show arff`. In my first attempt it showed the url for a google code site (which is defunct now). Try removing the current arff package and install the one at https://pypi.org/project/liac-arff/ with `pip install liac-arff`. Your code should work with the liac-arff package.